# SocketServer.TCPSocket works on stock python, but not python compiled against MSVCRT100 with newer OpenSSL

Tags: python, windows, sockets

Environment:

- Python 2.7.1 (Built against MSVCRT100)
- Windows 7

The code is:

```
import ssl
import socket
socket = socket.socket()
socket = ssl.wrap_socket(socket, keyfile='key', certfile='cert', server_side=True)
```

While this works fine on mac os x, this fails on windows with:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Interestingly, this works if a standard python is used, which is using OpenSSL 0.9.8l
 - As far as I can tell, I've compiled python and OpenSSL 0.9.8r using defaults as much as possible.

How should I get this code to work - alternatively, how should I investigate the culprit?

Comment: (How do I put a bounty on this question?)

Answer (score 2):

The following error says that, "socket is not connected"

```
socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

the [ssl.wrap_socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket) method uses lazy context construction:

> For server-side sockets, if the socket has no remote peer, it is assumed to be a listening socket, and the server-side SSL wrapping is automatically performed on client connections accepted via the accept() method.

Somehow, this is broken for Python 2.7 with MSVCRT100,
just call *ssl.wrap_socket()* after *accept()*

Answer (score 1):

There are some major issues when compiling Python 2.7.1 with msvcrt100. Among those is the fact that Microsoft changed some errno code between msvcrt90 and msvcrt100.

If you want it to work, you will have to patch Python quite a lot, following the indications on those 2 pages:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/VS2010

http://bugs.python.org/issue13210

Otherwise you should move to Python 3.3 which will include all those corrections for VS2010.